# ASP.NET Read only data from database

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a form and need to display data from a database as read only. Is there a way to do this?

Example:

Client Name: Fred's Trucking

Fred's Trucking would be from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just display this data in a static control (I.e label, read only text box, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Just display the data. Your code is what makes it read only. Use an asp:label instead of a form control.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you would want to display "Fred's Trucking" in a TextBox control, a TextBox control has a "ReadOnly" property that you would set to "True".

Answer (score 0):

www.ASP.net has a variety of examples

Walkthrough: Basic Data Access in Web Pages

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw738475.aspx